# UrbanAirship app crashes upon receipt of message

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Working on upgrading my UrbanAirship to 7.2. No compilation errors and the app runs fine until it receives a push message. At that point, it crashes with the following stack trace:

> UALib: ManifestUtils - Unable to find class:
>   com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver
>                                                                                     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.urbanairship.util.ManifestUtils.validateManifest(ManifestUtils.java:215)
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship.validateManifest(UAirship.java:736)
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship.executeTakeOff(UAirship.java:343)
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship.access$000(UAirship.java:42)
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship$2.run(UAirship.java:299)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.xxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.xxx-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                         at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285) 
>                                                                                         at
>   com.urbanairship.util.ManifestUtils.validateManifest(ManifestUtils.java:215) 
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship.validateManifest(UAirship.java:736) 
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship.executeTakeOff(UAirship.java:343) 
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship.access$000(UAirship.java:42) 
>                                                                                         at com.urbanairship.UAirship$2.run(UAirship.java:299) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                 ... 10 more
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available

When I check to see if the class is visible (Cmd-O) and start typing, the class comes up immediately.

Has anyone encountered this? I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest file? I think you might be missing the receiver in the manifest file

Comment: @android_Muncher is probably right. Make sure it is in there. And if it already is, try a clean build, Android Studio does inexplicable things sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We renamed GCMPushReceiver to GcmPushReceiver. You should remove all the Urban Airship receivers, services, and activities from your manifest and let auto manifest integration merge them for you.